# Trying to remove trim away indexes that aren't the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have three pandas data frames, each with values and indexes. The indexes are of type String. I'm trying to sort through each of them and remove all indexes that are not in all three data frames. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to remove any indexes at all.

I'm wondering what I could be doing differently here?

Below I have both of my loops to do this:

```
for day in TZThree_data.index:
    if day not in TZOne_data.index:
        TZThree_data.drop(index = day)
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day)
    if day not in BearCreek_data.index:
        TZThree_data.drop(index = day)
        if day in TZOne_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day)

for day in TZOne_data.index:
    if day not in TZThree_data.index:
        TZOne_data.drop(index = day)
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day)
    if day not in BearCreek_data.index:
        TZOne_data.drop(index = day)
        if day in TZThree_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day)
```

day: String type index
TZThree_data: one of my data sets
TZOne_data: another data set
BearCreek_data: my last data set

I've tried the above code, and I was expecting to get an output where all of the indexes were the same, and the number of values were the same. However, they remain totally unchanged.

Comment: please share you code as text, not an image. You are not dropping rows `inplace`. That's is the main issue. You have written nested if conditions that is the next issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm new to python and coding in general, so I'm not really sure what you mean by "dropping rows inplace", and I can't see what's wrong with the nested if conditions. Would you mind explaining a bit more? Sorry!

Comment: You need indices that are common in all three dataframes?

Comment: Yes. They all have at least some in common and some that are different. My original strategy was to sort through one, checking if the others had those values, then sort through the next and check if the others had those values, etc., removing any that did not appear in all three.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not dropping the data in-place. In pandas when you use `df.drop()` it defaults to keeping the original df the same and returning a new one with he dropped index. In your case the `BearCreek_data.drop(index = day)` needs to become `BearCreek_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)` (`BearCreek_data = BearCreek_data.drop(index = day)` would also work). In general pandas has excellent documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) which can be very helpful for issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You dropping certain rows from every dataframe. For example, `TZThree_data.drop(index = day)` drops a specific row assuming the if condition is True. And it returns the dropped dataframe that you are not assigning back to `TZThree_data` like `TZThree_data = TZThree_data.drop(index = day)`. So original dataframes remain unchanged. If you want to make changes in the dataframe itself without any assignment as above, you have to provide argument `inplace=True` as below.

Also your code tries to change dataframes inside for loop (which is not advisible), so more if conditions are required to ensure that the index we drop are available in the dataframe.

```py
# three for loops to process three dataframes
# iterate over a copy of index as we make changes to the original dataframes
# make changes inplace 
# before dropping an index ensure it is available

for day in TZThree_data.index.copy():
    if day not in TZOne_data.index:
        if day in TZThree_data.index:
            TZThree_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
    if day not in BearCreek_data.index:
        if day in TZThree_data.index:
            TZThree_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in TZOne_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)

for day in TZOne_data.index.copy():
    if day not in TZThree_data.index:
        if day in TZOne_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
    if day not in BearCreek_data.index:
        if day in TZOne_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in TZThree_data.index:
            TZThree_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)

for day in BearCreek_data.index.copy():
    if day not in TZThree_data.index:
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in TZOne_data.index:
            TZOne_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
    if day not in TZOne_data.index:
        if day in BearCreek_data.index:
            BearCreek_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
        if day in TZThree_data.index:
            TZThree_data.drop(index = day, inplace=True)
```

Anyway, simple and straightforward code is to obtain common indices and slice them:

```py
# get a set of common indices
common_indices = set(TZThree_data.index) & set(TZOne_data.index) & set(BearCreek_data.index)

# convert it into a list to do slicing
common_indices = list(common_indices)

# slice common indices in dataframes
BearCreek_data = BearCreek_data.loc[common_indices]
TZOne_data = TZOne_data.loc[common_indices]
TZThree_data = TZThree_data.loc[common_indices]
```

Comment: great. If your problem is resolved you can accept the answer. It would help others.